# How to share Leaflet web map with local data

Tags: leaflet

I create a web map using Leaflet. I access my map through localhost. However now I want to share with other persons. But I have local data. If I open the HTML it only presents the base maps. How can I share my local data?

Comment: If you are running your map from your server and data is also on your server, then there is no difference where you run it from, your local computer or from anywhere else in  internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the most cases the HTML is just the root for your webmap. You have various dependencies like css-files, js-files or geodata.

All the data is usually stored in different folders, named like css, js, data, etc. 
If you want to share a webmap running on localhost, you will have to share the other folders and files, too.

E.g. a leaflet map exported with qgis2web looks like following:

[image]